# undefined reference to `MPI

Tags: installation, mpi

I am trying to install The Scalable Parallel Random Number Generators Library (SPRNG) but I am having problems. The configure stage runs fine but when I try to make it I get the following output:

```
../../lib/libsprng.a(libsprng_a-communicate.o): In function `get_proc_info_mpi(int*, int*)':
/home/fangel/Downloads/sprng4.4/SRC/communicate.cpp:13: undefined reference to `MPI_Comm_rank'
../../lib/libsprng.a(libsprng_a-communicate.o): In function `make_new_seed_mpi()':
/home/fangel/Downloads/sprng4.4/SRC/communicate.cpp:28: undefined reference to `MPI_Comm_dup'
/home/fangel/Downloads/sprng4.4/SRC/communicate.cpp:30: undefined reference to `MPI_Comm_rank'
/home/fangel/Downloads/sprng4.4/SRC/communicate.cpp:31: undefined reference to `MPI_Comm_size'
/home/fangel/Downloads/sprng4.4/SRC/communicate.cpp:36: undefined reference to `MPI_Bcast'
/home/fangel/Downloads/sprng4.4/SRC/communicate.cpp:38: undefined reference to `MPI_Comm_free'
../../lib/libsprng.a(libsprng_a-communicate.o): In function `get_proc_info_mpi(int*, int*)':
/home/fangel/Downloads/sprng4.4/SRC/communicate.cpp:14: undefined reference to `MPI_Comm_size'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[4]: *** [check.clfg] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/fangel/Downloads/sprng4.4/check/lfg'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/fangel/Downloads/sprng4.4/check/lfg'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/fangel/Downloads/sprng4.4/check'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/fangel/Downloads/sprng4.4'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I guess this is related to a wrong configuration of MPI but I am not able to solve the problem. I would appreciate any help.

Thank you Hristo, it seems to go further after:
    ./configure CXX=mpicxx F77=mpif77

and changing to
   #include 
in communicate.cpp but I am still getting errors. This is the end of the current output:

```
 check_flfg-check_genf.o:     /home/fangel/Downloads/sprng4.4/check/lfg/F77/check_genf.F:218: more undefined references to `ffree_rng_' follow
 check_flfg-check_genf.o: In function `test_generator':
 /home/fangel/Downloads/sprng4.4/check/lfg/F77/check_genf.F:26: undefined reference to `fmake_new_seed_'
 /home/fangel/Downloads/sprng4.4/check/lfg/F77/check_genf.F:27: undefined reference to `fmake_new_seed_'
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
 make[5]: *** [check.flfg] Error 1
 make[5]: Leaving directory `     /home/fangel/Downloads/sprng4.4/check/lfg/F77'
 make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
 make[4]: Leaving directory `     /home/fangel/Downloads/sprng4.4/check/lfg/F77'
 make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
 make[3]: Leaving directory `     /home/fangel/Downloads/sprng4.4/check/lfg'
 make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
 make[2]: Leaving directory `     /home/fangel/Downloads/sprng4.4/check'
 make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
 make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/fangel/Downloads/sprng4.4'
 make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Then I changed the end of all the lines in fwrap.h from " __ " to "_". The errors are different now. I am getting an error related to the path /home/steve/... which does not exist in my computer:

```
 check_flcg-check_genf.o: In function `MAIN__':
 /home/steve/sprng4.4/check/lcg/F77/<stdin>:26: undefined reference to `fmake_new_seed__'
```

However I was able to successfully make the programs of the folders TESTS and EXAMPLES. The problem is only in the folder check... I do not see how to move the path from /home/steve/... to the right path.

Comment: Do you use `mpicc` (or whatever name your MPI C++ wrapper has) to also link the final executable? Looks like the MPI library is missing from the link command.

Comment: Where should I check for that? inside the Makefile? I can see this section in the Makefile:
    MPICOMPILE =  
    MPICXX = /usr/bin/mpicxx 
    MPIF77 = /usr/bin/mpif77
    MPILINK = 
    MPI_DEF = -DSPRNG_MPI
Is is this useful?

Comment: The documentation seems wrong. `configure` detects the MPI compiler wrappers but still uses the non-wrapped compilers to link the test programs. Rerun the configure process as `./configure CXX=mpicxx F77=mpif77`. Also there is an error at the beginning of `communicate.cpp`: `#include <mpi/mpi.h>` should be corrected to `#include <mpi.h>`

Comment: Thank you Hristo, it goes further now... but I am still getting errors. I copied my current output, after applying your suggestions, in the main box above.

Comment: I had the same problem but thought it could be Intel-specific. After you update the symbol names in `fwrap.h`, go to `SRC` and type `make clean`, then go back to the main source directory and run `make`. This will rebuild `libsprng.a` with correct Fortran symbol names.